# How to reduce the thickness of letters

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-printing, text-object

I want to reduce the thickness of a letter but don't know how.

The dimensions of my letter are 7 cm x 7cm and the letter is roughly 5mm thick.
I want to reduce the thickness to 4mm but I want the letter to keep the dimensions 7cm x 7cm

Is it possible ?

[image]

Answer (score 12):

The *Shrink/Fatten* tool seems like a good fit.
Just select the faces you want to move, and shrink them.

[image]

Comment: Because you select the top and bottom of the 'ledge' it becomes a lot thinner or a lot fatter than the rest of the letter, perhaps only select the bottom.  Also selecting the back of the ledge makes it shorter or longer, which also changes the shape.