# How do I scale a letter how it should be?

Tags: edit-mode, edges, text-object

I would like to extrude & scale the outter edge of my letter like this :

[image: Like This]

but Actually it looks like this ...

[image: :(]

I have no clue how to do it ...

Also  there is another problem,  if I scale a mesh is there a way to deactivate the z axis ?

Comment: Hello :). Perhaps related: [How to reduce the thickness of letters](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/187860/78972)

Comment: I think the linked answer is right, but you have first to extrude the object along Z otherwise the Shrink/Fatten tool doesn't work right. You can delete the duplicate geometry afterwards

Answer (score 2):

To deactivate $Z$ you can scale pressing <kbd>S</kbd> followed by <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>.

$X$ and $Y$ will still scale.
Also the transform panel have little lock icons that you can toggle to lock different properties (like $Z$ scale).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but you can try <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to scale along normals.

Answer (score 0):

For the text you can use the offset value:

[image]

Comment: hmm . idk so i turned it into a mesh   did Strg+I to do a little invert .. because if i do a bigger one it bugs .. so i wanted to extrude the outter edge  so it gets bigger but idk how .  thanks for the tip witht he Z Axis